# Output of NIntegrate depends on MaxRecursion

Tags: numerical-integration, integral-equations

I have an integral in this form:

```
NIntegrate[ (5184(-11 + k(98 + k(-16 + k(-40 + k(17 + 2k(7 + k)))))))/
  ((1 + E^((1/2)(-1 + k)))(1 + k)^3(-7 + k*(2 + k))^3), {k, 0, Infinity}]
```

when I set , `MaxRecursion` to `12` answer is of the order of `10^11` when set to `30` answer is of order `10^25` when set `40` order is `10^28` when set to `100` and above order is `10^34` and is constant up to `400` but I have an error in answer.

How should I proceed to get the correct result?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basics of the site. Once you gain enough reputation by making [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you will be able to vote up and down both questions and answers. When you see good ones, please vote them up by clicking the grey triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. As you receive help, try to give it too, by *answering questions* in your area of expertise.

Comment: You get *"an error"* that actually contains information *"Integrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 100 recursive bisections"*.

Comment: yes rhermans this is my integral error.

Comment: The function diverges at $(2 \sqrt{2}-1)$, and it looks like the integral also diverges, the answer then is `Infinity`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are too many singularities in your integrand (according to `Reduce` there are infinity of them, but these are complex valued) and then there are 3 real valued poles `{-1., -3.82843, 1.82843}` (I did not check for zero/pole cancellations). So the only real pole in the range of the integration is `1.82843` or `-1 + 2 Sqrt[2]`

```
integrand = 5184 ((-11 + k (98 + k (-16 + k (-40 + k (17 + 2 k (7 + k))))))/
    ((1 + E^(1/2 (-1 + k))) (1 + k)^3 (-7 + k (2 + k))^3));
poles = Reduce[Denominator[integrand] == 0, k]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So trying to integrate this is a losing battle. But you can get little better numbers if you exclude the `-1 + 2 Sqrt[2]` and increase `WorkingPrecision`. At least the order of the numerical result does not change as much.

```
 NIntegrate[integrand, {k, 0, Infinity}, Method -> PrincipalValue, 
  Exclusions -> -1 + 2 Sqrt[2], MaxRecursion -> 12, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With `MaxRecursion -> 30`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With `MaxRecursion -> 40`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With `MaxRecursion -> 100`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

btw, `Integrate` says also it does not converge:

```
   Integrate[integrand, {k, 0, Infinity}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So may be you need to change the integrand?

Answer (score 3):

The consistent behavior displayed by the OP's integral -- increase recursion, increase the magnitude of the integral -- normally is the result of a divergent integral.  It's possible the OP seeks the principal value of the integral.  There is one pole of order 3 in the interval of integration

```
f = (5184 (-11 + k (98 + k (-16 + k (-40 + k (17 + 2 k (7 + k))))))) / 
       ((1 + E^((1/2) (-1 + k))) (1 + k)^3 (-7 + k*(2 + k))^3);

Solve[Denominator[f] == 0 && k > 0, k, Reals]
pole = k /. First[%];

(*  {{k -> -1 + 2 Sqrt[2]}, {k -> -1 + 2 Sqrt[2]}, {k -> -1 + 2 Sqrt[2]}}  *)
```

Since the order is odd there is some hope that the principal value exists.  But it does not exist since the series expansion shows that the term of degree -2 does not vanish:

```
N@Series[f, {k, pole, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If one is interested in further confirmation, subtract out the divergent term and see whether the integral converges:

```
coeff = SeriesCoefficient[f, {k, pole, -2}]; 
NIntegrate[f - coeff/(k - pole)^2, {k, 0, pole, Infinity}, Method -> "PrincipalValue"]

(*  -277.122  *)
```